# INVALID_ARGUMENT or "Unknown resource type" error when deploying Google Cloud Function from Source Repository

Tags: function, google-cloud-platform, cloud

I was not able to deploy my cloud functions from the Source Repository. It was failing with some non-helpful error like "Unknown resource type". I was able to finally get it working and thought it could help others as well by posting this question.

Answer (score 1):

When specifying "Directory with source code", try adding the sub-folder without a prefix of '/'. That seemed to help me. Note however that the / comes back if you "Edit" the cloud function..